# If I buy a motherboard will it have the latest BIOS?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

So I’m looking to replace my aging system and so I’m going to go with the latest intel kaby lake CPU line, but I personally can’t justify the cost of getting a z270 motherboard. So I was going to get an older motherboard as the CPU would still work with it, but the B110 chipset motherboard would probably need a bios update to work with it. The motherboard supports it after BIOS P7.30.

My question is if I buy this will it come with the latest BIOS and if not will I at least be able to update it? I really don't have the money for mistakes:

- **Motherboard**: [ASRock H110M-HDS](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H110M-HDS/)
- **CPU**: [Intel® Core™ i3-7350K Processor 
  (4M Cache, 4.20 GHz)](https://ark.intel.com/products/97527/Intel-Core-i3-7350K-Processor-4M-Cache-4_20-GHz)

I’m also considering getting a Pentium g4560 rather than the i3 as i'm rather broke.

Comment: There is no way for you to predict which revision of the firmware the motherboard will have.  It entirely depends on the age of the stock the store has

Comment: If it doesn't have the BIOS I need, can I update it without buying any other hardware? I do have a USB drive

Comment: Depends; Check the manual some motherboards have that feature some require a compatible CPU to be installed

Comment: You have done yourself a disservice by accepting an incomplete answer so quickly.  Your unlikely to get multiple answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we cannot know which version BIOS chip shipped with the particular production round your physical board will have been produced in; This motherboard does have a UEFI BIOS that has an internet flash feature. 
This means it's able to be updated to the latest BIOS over the internet and won't even need a second computer to download it with.

Edit: Definitely misunderstood the question at first. If your BIOS ships without the necessary update to use the CPU, you will be unable to access the UEFI. Without a second CPU to use that's compatible, or additional hardware if the chip is removable, you will be unable to update the BIOS and will be left without a functioning build.

Comment: But If it doesn't support the CPU at all I can't update it? Yes or no

Comment: My apologies, I definitely misread your question.
See ASRock's cpu compatability chart here, it does indeed support the architechture, may need to update the BIOS though when you get it:http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H110M-HDS/?cat=CPU

Comment: @BenJacobson - It still does not appear you grasp the question.  The author is buying a motherboard with an unknown revision of the firmware, and the CPU he wants to use requires a specific version of the firmware, hence their question.  So their ultimate question is, will they be able update to the supported firmware, if they only have an incompatible CPU instaled

Comment: @Ben Jacobson I've already read it and know the CPU is on the support list, but only after the BOIS P7.30. I want to know that in the event the BOIS version is older I can still update it to support the CPU in some way

Comment: You're absolutely right, that completely eluded me,so sorry about that.

Indeed, if your BIOS ships without the necessary version, there is not a way to update without additional hardware as a functional CPU will be required to access the UEFI to flash the update.

Comment: @BenJacobson Thank you, the answer I was looking for